# What's the use for the special ipv6 addresses in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, ip, hostname, ipv6, hosts

I have the following block in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

---

They were inserted by some automagic in Ubuntu and not written by me. I've found lots of documents that say that you should have these lines. But why? Why are they desirable?

My suspicion is that they *aren't* and are just cruft (except for the first one). Because if you google one of the names, eg `ip6-allrouters`, all you find are references to `/etc/hosts` but no one is actually using them.

Another way of phrasing this question is, what harm will come unto me or what feature will not function properly if I remove these lines? If the answer is *none*, can we conclude that they are redundant?

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone in Debian just made up those names. They don't appear in any official documents and no other distributions, not derived from Debian, have them. If something _does_ break from removing them, it's most likely a bug.

Comment: Cool! Let's try and find a source for that. If it is true, then that is proof that they are redundant.

Comment: How do you prove something doesn't exist?

Comment: Perhaps we can find the commit which added the names and ask whoever committed it why he or she did it?

Answer (score 14):

According to [RFC 4291, Section 2.7: Multicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7), the first 8 bits (`FF` in `FF0X`) at the beginning of identifies the address as a **muticast** address.

---

The **flags**, the next 4 bits, (the first `0` in `FF0X`) in the question indicate:

> ... a permanently-assigned ("well-known") multicast address, assigned
> by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).

---

The next 4 bits, (the last hex value `0` or `2` in `FF00` or `FF02`) define the **scope**:

```
 0 reserved
 [...]
 2  Link-Local scope
 [...]
```

The **reserved** scope is reserved for future use.

The **Link-local** scope means, that packages within that scope will never be routed and therefore cannot leave the subnet.

---

So the addesses mean he following:

- `::1:` This is the loopback address, whose IPv4-equivalent is `127.0.0.1`.
- `fe00::0`: Can be compared to the [Class E address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) in IPv4, therefore it's in the reserved scope; reserved for future use.
- `ff02::1`: The group of all IPv6 nodes (including the routers) in the Link-local scope, whose IPv4-equivalent is `224.0.0.1`.
- `ff02::2`: The group of all IPv6 routers in the Link-local scope, whose IPv4-equivalent is `224.0.0.2`.
- `ff02::3`: This exists no longer an is unassigned at the moment. Earlier it stood for the group of all hosts (excluding the routers) in the Link-local scope.

---

**Further reading / References**:

- [RFC 4291: IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)
- [RFC 6890: Special-Purpose IP Address Registries](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)
- [RFC 7346: IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7346)
- [RFC 2365: Administratively Scoped IP Multicast](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2365) (see section 8)
- [IANA: IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)
- [IANA: IPv6 Multicast Address Space Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml)
- [IANA: IPv6 Address Space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.txt)

Answer (score 5):

I think their purpose is so you can more easily i.e. ping all routers or all hosts etc without having to remember the multicast addresses. I haven't seen them being used anywhere else either.